# How to perform chops with gloves in Secret of Mana?

Tags: secret-of-mana

I always wondered how to exactly perform chops with the gloves weapon in Secret of Mana.

The computer often does them, and sometimes I do them too. But I don't know how to consistently perform them.

I recently tried to attack from behind the enemies and it seemed to be more successful, but I'm not sure if it's simply luck or something else.

I discovered there are different chops depending on which level of concentration you release, but the likelihood to chop combined with the time needed to concentrate made them occur something like three times in the last playthrough I've done.

So is there a way to be sure to chop? Or is it random?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's random but can't say for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that as with most attacks, it's partly random and partly based on your attack %, meaning you might have better odds if you're always attacking at empty % instead of spamming. But then again, I haven't played that game for about 10 years, so I can't be sure.